# Using AngularJS or how to call rest services from CustomApp

Tags: angularjs, rally

I would like to know if it is possible to add angularjs to the custom app in Rally, or as alternative how to call REST services from a Rally Custom app. Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of making a WS API call from an Angular app from inside Rally's custom page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
    <div ng-controller="MyController" >
    <button ng-click="myData.doClick(item, $event)">Send AJAX Request to Rally</button>
    <br/>
    Data from server: {{myData.fromServer}}
  </div>

  <script>
    angular.module("myapp", [])
        .controller("MyController", function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.myData = {};
            $scope.myData.doClick = function(item, event) {

                var responsePromise = $http.get("https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defect");

                responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.myData.fromServer = data.QueryResult.Results[0];
                    console.log(data);
                });
                responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert("AJAX failed!");
                });
            }


        } );    
  </script>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using external CDN within app is expected to produce Mixed Content error if accessing over http. It works if https is used. Here is the first query result (a defect from my current project) is returned.

[image]